# How to test checkbox visibility

Tags: android, android-testing

I'm using instrumented test for test purposes. I want to create a test to see when certain conditions are met, see if checkbox visible or not. I've tried something simple like that

```
@Test
public void testCheckboxVisibility(){
    myPresenter.conditionOne = x;
    myPresenter.conditionTwo = y;
    myPresenter.handleOptionsUI() // set visibility,state and enable for all checkbox under conditions
    assertFalse(myPresenter.getVisibilityOfCheckbox(CheckboxAction.MY_CHECKBOX);
}
```

on presenter visibility method looks like this

```
public boolean getVisibilityOfCheckbox(CheckboxAction action){
   int index = findIndexOfCheckboxAction(action);
   return (CheckboxModel) action.visibility;
}
```

on presenter findIndex looks like this

```
public int findIndexOfCheckboxAction(CheckboxAction action){
    for(int i=0; i< checkboxOptions.size(); i++)
    {
      CheckboxModel model = ((CheckboxModel) checkboxOptions.get(i));
      if(model.checkboxAction = action){ return i }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

As you can understand we use checkbox through a model that include checkbox configuration (icon, scale, colour, name etc.) and they are on a recyclerView. On my attempt the list is always empty so that it's not working. How can i test that scenario. Lastly, we gonna use these to test on Firebase testlab over android studio.

**Edit 1:**

I've tried to reach my goal with espresso but recyclerView was empty and it crashed.

```
  @Rule
    public FragmentTestRule<?, myFragment> fragmentTestRule =
            FragmentTestRule.create(myFragment.class);


  @Test
    public void testCheckboxVisibility(){
        myPresenter.conditionOne = x;
        myPresenter.conditionTwo = y;
        myPresenter.handleOptionsUI() // set visibility,state and enable for all checkbox under conditions
        onData(anything()).atPosition(1).onChildView(withId(R.id.options_recyclerView)).perform(click());
    }
```